# Resize 3D Objects in python without operator function

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, scale, operator

I want to move objects with the resize function, while enabling Transform affects only to location. In 3D-Editor it is easy to give them the direction, so that the objects move away from center.

Now I want to implement this in python and resize it via script. I could only find the operator function "bpy.ops.resize()" which I don't want to use.
If you have other suggestions creating this movement would be good as well.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple vector maths.**

The global location of any object is `gl = ob.matrix_world.translation`

The global location of the cursor is `cl = scene.cursor.location`

The vector that describes the distance and direction from object to cursor is the difference `d = gl - cl`

To move to a scaled location

```
ob.matrix_world.translation = cl + scale_factor * d
```

or similarly

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
cursor_loc = scene.cursor.location

scale_factor = 1.1

for o in scene.objects:
    d = o.matrix_world.translation - cursor_loc
    o.matrix_world.translation += (scale_factor - 1) * d
```